# Rails link_to with inline styling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I must change a link_to tag color without using a CSS class, how can I do? I've tried something such as

```
<%= link_to item.description, {}, {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => "css_class"} %>
```

but it doesn't works on ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.1

Comment: Use the developer tools of your browser to check wether the issue is from rails (styles & class not generated), or if the issue is on the css side

Comment: Firebug retrieve me the following: <a href="/warehouses/orderby?html%5Bstyle%5D=color%3A+%23FFFFFF">Asset</a>

Answer (score 38):

How about

```
<%= link_to item.description, nil, {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => "css_class"} %>
```

...or...

```
<%= link_to item.description, '#', {:style=>'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => "css_class"} %>
```

Answer (score 20):

This should work with Rails 3

```
link_to item.description, :style=> 'color:#FFFFFF;', :class => 'css_class'
```

With the new syntax in rails 4, it becomes

```
link_to item.description, style: 'color:#FFFFFF;', class: 'css_class'
```

Answer (score 9):

I want to update this topic, because in this time, the syntax is different.
In rails 4+, the correct syntax is:

```
<%= link_to TEXT, URL, class: 'css_class', style: 'color:#FFFFFF' %>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try `link_to item.description, {}, {:style => 'color: #FFFFFF'}` is ok.

To color your links you have to set more then `color`:

```
a:link { 
  color: #333333;
}
a:visited { 
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover { 
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
a:active { 
  color: #333333;
}
```

I recommend to use a css class for this.

Comment: To set a class you have to set ...` :class => 'nameOfClass'`

Comment: Ok suppose that I've :class => 'test_color' how can I definy my CSS stylesheet? I meen something such as                      #test_color{a:link { 
  color: #333333;
}
a:visited { 
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
a:hover { 
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
a:active { 
  color: #333333;
}
}

Comment: This is a good answer.  You don't need a class or curly braces in your link_to in order to accomplish this.  Just copy the css from this answer into your CSS file, and the link_to links will color accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
= link_to name, url, style: 'color:#FFFFFF;'
```

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure this code will work.

`<%= link_to "button_name",{:controller => 'controller_name', :action => 'action_name'},{:style=>"color:#fff;"}%>`

Comment: `:style=>"color:#fff !important;"`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a class called `test-color`, you can assign the `:hover` selector to that class by joining the class name and the :hover selector together.

Class hooks begin with a dot(.), IDs begin with a hash(#)

```css
.test-color:link {
  color: #333333;
}
.test-color:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.test-color:hover {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}
.test-color:active {
  color: #333333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

link_to can be written as

```
<%= link_to text, path, class: "" %>
```

Or

```
<%= path, class: "" do %>
  <div>
    <!-- Insert HTML here -->
  </div>
<% end %>
```