# How to change my link color on Rails code?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, colors, hyperlink

I'm trying to change the following Rails link into primary color (it's currently white):

```
<%= link_to 'Edit' %>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails link\_to with inline styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768518/rails-link-to-with-inline-styling)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `class` to your link after providing the path.

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_path, class: "a-primary" %>
```

And add styles for that class.

```
.a-primary{
  /* styles for link */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your application has a common style, there's no need to define a CSS class. Just write the CSS for `<a>` tags in general:

```
a:link, a:visited {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center; 
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Ruby code

```
<%= link_to 'Edit' , '#'%>
```

Rails renders the link_to script as a normal hyperlink in HTML.

```
<a href="#" > Edit</a>
```

then the browser will apply the style to all hyperlinks in the app.